# Mostrar un desplegable (dropdown) dentro de la pagina

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla con un *dropdown* en cada fila con acciones. El problema que tengo es que en las últimas filas al presionar el *dropdown* tengo que scrollear la tabla para abajo para poder ver las opciones. No me aparecen directamente.

Pienso que es alguna configuración de `CSS` que no puedo solucionar.

**Mi tabla:**

```
$object = new CRUD();

// Design initial table header
$data = '<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
               <tr>
                   <th >Nombre</th>
                   <th>Apellido</th>
                   <th>Paquete</th>
                   <th>$ Venta</th>
                   <th>$ Emision</th>
                   <th>Vendedor</th>
                   <th>$ Dif</th>
                   <th>Acciones</th>
               </tr>
         </div>';    

$users = $object->Read();

if (count($users) > 0) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $link = $user['link'];


             $data .= '<tr>
                  <td>' . $user['first_name'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $user['last_name'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $user['paq'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $user['pventa'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $user['pcosto'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $user['vendedor'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $user['dif'] . '</td>
                  <td>     
                     <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Acciones
                          <span class="caret"></span></button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank">Comprobante</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a onclick="GetUserDetails2(' . $user['id'] . ')">Ver +</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="GetUserDetails(' . $user['id'] . ')">Editar</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="DeleteUser(' . $user['id'] . ')">Borrar</a></li>    
                          </ul>
                     </div>    
            </tr>';

    }
} else {
    // records not found
    $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No hay pasajeros cargados.</td></tr>';
}

$data .= '</table>';

echo $data;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que tu problema pueda solucionarse utilizando css únicamente. Sin embargo como veo que utilizas Bootstrap si que hay una manera sencilla de que se muestre siempre dentro de la parte visible de la página utilizando javascript.

Se pueden utilizar los eventos que genera bootstrap `shown.bs.dropdown` y `hidden.bs.dropdown` para determinar cuando un desplegable se muestra y calcular en ese momento si el desplegable se muestra por debajo de la parte visible de la pagina, y utilizar la clase `.dropup` que proporciona bootstrap para que los desplegables se muestren por arriba.

Aquí un ejemplo utilizando jQuery:

```
$('div.table-responsive').on("shown.bs.dropdown", ".dropdown", function() {

  var desplegable = $(this).children('ul.dropdown-menu');
  var boton = $(this).children(".dropdown-toggle");

  var separaciondesplegable = desplegable.offset();

  var espacioArriba = (separaciondesplegable.top - boton.height() - desplegable.height()) - $(window).scrollTop();

  var espacioAbajo = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - (separaciondesplegable.top + desplegable.height());

  if (espacioAbajo < 0 && (espacioArriba >= 0 || espacioArriba > espacioAbajo))
      $(this).addClass("dropup");

}).on("hidden.bs.dropdown", ".dropdown", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("dropup");
});
```

[Demostración en jsfiddle con comentarios en el código](https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/oqwgtqpv/1/)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudó mucho!

Comment: Cómo tendría que cambiar la variable  espacioAbajo para que me tome la distancia hasta donde termina mi tabla y no hasta el final del windows? Porque si tengo una tabla que ocupa la mitad de la pantalla sigo teniendo el problema, pero si la tabla ocupa todo el largo de la pantalla funciona correctamente.

Comment: @Santiago mejor que cambiar la variable creo que seria conveniente añadir otra que sirva para comprobar esa condición. Aquí un ejemplo.https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/dvz38x9y/1/

Comment: Ahora sí queda bien para todos los casos! Muchas gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`dropup`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) (*ver ejemplo 2*) solo para las ultimas filas o todas.

Ejemplo:

```css
#table.table-responsive {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="table" class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <td>Algo</td>
      <td width="100px">
        <!-- ACA Usamos "dropup" en lugar de "dropdown" -->
        <div class="dropup">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Acciones
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- ACA Agregamos "pull-right" para que se despliegue hacia la derecha -->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Comprobante</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a onclick="GetUserDetails2(id)">Ver +</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="GetUserDetails(id)">Editar</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="DeleteUser(id)">Borrar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```